# High Speed Serial

Tags: linux

I have a system which uses a UART clocked at 26 Mhz. This is a 16850 UART on a i86 architecture. I have no problems accessing the port. The largest incoming message is about 56 bytes, the largest outgoing about 100. The baud rate divisor needs to be 1 so seterial /dev/ttyS4 baud_base 115200 is OK and opening at 115200. There is no flow control. Specifying part 16850 does NOT set the FIFO to deep. I was losing bytes. All the data is byte, unsigned char.

I wrote a routine that uses ioperm to set the deep FIFO's to 64 and now a read/write works meaning that the deep FIFO's are NOT being enabled by serial_core.c or 8250.c, at least in a deep manner.

With the deep FIFO set using s brute force, post open(fd, "/dev/ttyS4", NO_BLOCKING, etc I get reliably the correct number of bytes but I tend to get the same word missing a bit. Not a byte, a bit.

All this same stuff runs fine under DOS so it is not a hardware issue.

I have opened the port for raw, no delays, no party, 8 bits, 2 stop.

Has anyone seen issues reading serial ports are relatively high speeds with short bursts of data?

Yes, I have tried custom baud, etc. The FIFO levels made the biggest improvement. This is a ISA bus card using IRQ7.

It appears the serial driver for Linux sucks and has way to much latency and far to many features for really basic raw operation.

Has anyone else tried very high speed data without flow control or had similar issues. As I stated, I get the correct number of bytes and all the data is correct except 1 bit in byte 4.

I am pretty stumped.

Comment: Maybe post some code to help others see what you are trying to do.

Comment: The 16C2850 fifo enables do not work correctly. I wrote my own driver to handle this. The standard Linux drivers are far to complicated with options for every possible thing except the obvious. A simple 3 wire io port optimized for speed.